# Input lag when I jump

Tags: lua, box2d, love2d

I'm working on a small game using lua with Löve2D, and I used this code to make my character jump:

```
epsilon = 0.1
x,y = player.body:getLinearVelocity() 
if math.abs(math.ceil(y)) < epsilon then cantJump = false else cantJump = true end
if love.keyboard.isDown(" ") and not cantJump then player.body:setLinearVelocity(0,-500) end
player.body:setAngle(0)
player.body:setX(math.ceil(player.body:getX()))
player.body:setY(math.ceil(player.body:getY()))
end
```

But sometimes, I have to wait a short time to see the player jumping when I press space button. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Why you are using `math.ceil()` here?

Comment: Side note: it is better to use positive semantics for your variables: `canJump` instead of `cantJump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the math.ceil. try removing it, since it is changing the player's position, or just move it to before you tell it to jump.